# What makes this "Sea Patrol" question opinion-based?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Apologies, but I don't fathom why [Why did Jim Roth and Swain die trying to defuse a bomb on an empty yacht, rather than save themselves and jump off?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/107022/13434) was closed as  "opinion-based"?

Doubtless I reasoned my question with "facts and citations".

Answer (score 1):

> Doubtless I reasoned my question with "facts and citations".

### That's not the issue.

The issue is that any answers would require opinions as **answers** as to why these characters acted the way they did....unless it's clearly stated in the show.

I gather that this is not the case.

The basic answer is *"because that's what the script/plot required"*

This is a **fictional drama** and characters often act irrationally and against their own best interests in such shows.

Even more often, characters are killed off for various reasons and having it happen in a spectacular fashion is not uncommon.